# Able to create Magento shipment programmatically but unable to mark it as shipped?

Tags: php, magento

I have the following code that would create a shipment for an order. But still the shipped item isn't marked as shipped. And SHIP button at the top is still there. Therefore, I cant create RMA if needed.

Please check screenshot ([link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/62230/429611/kTdVcLQNdeyr9Q7/Screen%20Shot%202014-03-31%20at%2011.24.32%20AM.png))

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order') -> loadByIncrementId($order_id);
$itemQty = $order -> getItemsCollection() -> count();

$convertOrder = new Mage_Sales_Model_Convert_Order();
$shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order) -> prepareShipment($itemQty);

$items = $order -> getAllItems();

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $shipped_item = $convertOrder -> itemToShipmentItem($item);
    $shipped_item -> setQty($item -> getQtyOrdered());
    $shipment -> addItem($shipped_item);
}

$shipment -> register();
$shipment -> setOrder($order);
$shipment -> save();
```

Comment: This link might be helpful http://code.marksserver.co.uk/magento/orders/programmatically-ship-and-complete-an-order/569/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always hop to the source for problems like these.  The code that determines if that button displays is here

```
    #File: app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View.php
    if ($this->_isAllowedAction('ship') && $order->canShip()
        && !$order->getForcedDoShipmentWithInvoice()) {
        $this->_addButton('order_ship', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship'),
            'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getShipUrl() . '\')',
            'class'     => 'go'
        ));
    }
```

Looking at that, your best bet is the `canShip` method

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
public function canShip()
{
    if ($this->canUnhold() || $this->isPaymentReview()) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->getIsVirtual() || $this->isCanceled()) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->getActionFlag(self::ACTION_FLAG_SHIP) === false) {
        return false;
    }

    foreach ($this->getAllItems() as $item) {
        if ($item->getQtyToShip()>0 && !$item->getIsVirtual()
            && !$item->getLockedDoShip())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Drop some `var_dump`/`Mage::log` debugging in here and you should be able to figure out why Magento thinks it needs to display the shipping button. Once you know that, you should be able to figure out what additional state you need to save.